# CentOS, Apache Vhosts enabled,but DOCUMENT_ROOT cant towards /home/auser/website/www1

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, vhost

## environment

> CentOS 6.5 x86_64
> Apache2.4.9 *(locate=/usr/local/apache2)*
> PHP 5.5.13 *(locate=/usr/local/php5)*
> Apache vhosts enabled.

**site1**

> > domain=localhost
> > path=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
> > rst=OK

**site2**

> > domain=phpmyadmin
> > path=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/phpmyadmin
> > rst=OK

**site3**

> > domain=phpmyadmin3
> > path=/home/default7/website/phpmyadmin
> > rst=You don't have permission to access /

**site4**

> > domain=mysite1
> > path=/home/default7/website/mysite1
> > result=You don't have permission to access /

When i turned off selinux,403 as the same.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered checking the permissions on the files in site 3 & 4?  They are both in your home directory.  The web server (user or group `apache` on CentOS) should have read access to these files.  Remember that for it to work, `apache` will need read access on the whole path from `/home` all the way to the relevant files.